# Get SharePoint list's column values using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

I want to get SharePoint Online lists column values using javascript. But my user don't have access to that lists or site so i need to pass SP online credentials and login to SPO. So how can i pass SPO authentication and fetch lists data.

Answer (score 0):

You could check [this library](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Online-d9fdb136/sourcecode?fileId=100090&pathId=1864657548) to authenticate SharePoint online by JavaScript, while this'll expose user name and password.

So I would suggest you check SPFx and elevated privileges using MS Flow.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51661.sharepoint-framework-spfx-webpart-with-elevated-privileges-using-ms-flow.aspx

Comment: I dont want to use MS flow. so i there any way i can directly pass site collection creds and get the SPList data. As in C# we have **`public SharePointOnlineCredentials(string username, SecureString password)`** class

Comment: No such api from client JavaScript api.